# Nodejs change db connection run time

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

[image]I need to change Nodejs MySQL database connection at runtime.

Here is my code,

```
var mysql=require('mysql'); 
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ host : 'localhost', user : 'root', password : '', database : 'test' }); 
var connection2 = mysql.createConnection({ host : 'localhost', user : 'root', password : '', database : 'test1' }); 
connection.connect(function(err) { if (err) throw err; console.log('You are now connected...'); }); connection2.connect(function(err) { if (err) throw err; console.log('You are now connected...'); });
```

Do you have any idea about it?

Please share with me.

Thanks.

Comment: run time means? Any code you have?

Comment: yes please see..

var mysql=require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'test'
});



var connection2 = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'test1'
});

 
connection.connect(function(err) {  
    if (err) throw err;
     console.log('You are now connected...');
    
});

connection2.connect(function(err) {  
    if (err) throw err;
     console.log('You are now connected...');
    

});

Comment: run time means?

Comment: When I select the drop down option, then my DB connection should be changed.

Comment: Did you understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL` offers a `changeUser` command that allows you to alter the current user and other aspects of the connection without shutting down the underlying socket:

Since you exported connection using `module exports`, you can `require` that as below

**var connection = require('./connection.js');**

```
var connection = require('./connection.js'); // your path

function changeConnection(db)

   connection.changeUser({database : 'my_database'}, function(err) { 
     if (err) throw err; 
   });
}
```

[Here is the documentation for the same](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#switching-users-and-altering-connection-state)

Comment: Actually, I created a separate connection file and require it's in my model so I am not understanding how can I changed my connection, and require it to in my all models files

Comment: means? I didnt get you

Comment: Please see in the question I have uploaded a picture.

Comment: picture? Where is it?

Comment: okay you can just `require` that connection using the file name

Comment: yes, I require that connection file in my model but how can I change that DB name in a connection.js file.

Comment: did you give correct path?, just `console.log(connection)` and check what you get

Comment: yes, I give correct path.and when pirnt by console.log(connection) it gave me connection object

Comment: _events:
 { data: [Function],
   end: [Array],
   handshake: [Function: boun
   unhandledError: [Function:
   drain: [Function: bound ],
   enqueue: [Function: bound
_eventsCount: 6,
_maxListeners: undefined,
readable: true,
writable: true,
_config:
 ConnectionConfig {
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 3306,
   localAddress: undefined,
   socketPath: undefined,
   user: 'root',
   password: undefined,
   database: 'iddna_test',
   connectTimeout: 10000,
   insecureAuth: false,
   supportBigNumbers: false,
   bigNumberStrings: false,
   dateStrings: false,

Comment: where you added `connection.destroy();` `mysql` packaged you used right?

Comment: var mysql=require('mysql');
var config=require('../config/config');
var connection=require('../config/connection'); 

 

exports.change_db_connection = function(req, res) {
  
   connection.destroy();

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({ host : 'localhost', user : 'root', password : '', database : 'enterprise_11_db' }); 
};

Comment: try with the first method and try `console.log(connection)` inside `change_db_connection` function

Comment: friend i have use that method it's working properly
connection.changeUser({database : 'my_database'}, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});

Comment: i have just change db name

Comment: yeah fine, I just saw that method. Even I ll update answer will that. It may be useful to anyone

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I hope it will serve the purpose.

```
var mysql=require('mysql'); 

function getConnection(db){
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({ host : 'localhost', user : 'root', password : '', database : db }); 
        connection.connect(function(err) { 
            if (err) throw err; 
            console.log('You are now connected...'); 
            return connection;
        });
}


var connection = getConnection(req.param.db); //req.param.db is a user input

// Here your code goes
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Need to change db connection only change database name

```
connection.changeUser({database : 'my_database'}, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```